# How to write aggregation function in Pandas with condition on other column

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions, apply, pandas-groupby

Suppose a dataframe df with columns a,b,c,d. 
I know the way of defining a function to aggregate values in Panda like:

```
def my_agg(x):
    names = {
        'a_Total': x['a'].sum(), 
        'b_Mean': x['b'].mean()
     }
    return pd.Series(names, index=['a_Total','b_Mean'])

d_aggregate = df.groupby(['c','d']).apply(my_agg)
```

What I am looking for is a way to take total or mean on a, b respectively based on selective values in column 'c' or 'd'.

Sample data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[10,20,30,40],
             "b":[1,2,3,4],
             "c":[c1,c1,c1,c2],
             "d":[100,200,300,400]})
```

My aggregate function:

```
def my_agg91(x):
names = {
    'Sum_a': x['a'].sum(),   
    'Mean_b': x['b'].mean()}

return pd.Series(names, index=['Sum_a','Mean_b'])

df2= df.groupby(['c']).apply(my_agg91)
```

which gives me:

```
    Sum_a  Mean_b
c                
c1   60.0     2.0
c2   40.0     4.0
```

What I want: Sum of 'a' for 'd'<250 and mean of 'b' for 'd'>250 (in single dataframe)
please suggest the changes in function to get output:

```
    Sum_a  Mean_b
c                
c1   30.0     3.0
c2    0.0     4.0
```

Comment: @ScottBoston I have added the sample data and output needed. Please let me know if it's not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter according in your function, like:

```py
def my_agg92(x):
   names = {
       'Sum_a': x[x['d'] < 250]['a'].sum(),   
       'Mean_b': x[x['d'] > 250]['b'].mean()}

   return pd.Series(names, index=['Sum_a','Mean_b'])

df.groupby(['c']).apply(my_agg92)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you tell me how to do this if I want to check for some string in 'd' instead of the value ?

Comment: If you column 'd' is of type string and you want to do some test, have a look at the pandas string functions, like contains: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html


It would be something like x[x['d'].str.contains('keyword')]['a'].sum()

Answer (score 0):

to avoid repetition I would suggest replace index with "[k for k,v in dict.items()]":

```
def my_agg92(x):
   names = {
       'Sum_a': x[x['d'] < 250]['a'].sum(),   
       'Mean_b': x[x['d'] > 250]['b'].mean()}

   return pd.Series(names, index=[k for k,v in names.items()])

df.groupby(['c']).apply(my_agg92)
```